# DaVinci Resolve 16 playback sound not working (Linux)

Tags: audio, davinci-resolve, linux

With default configuration there's no sound present.
[image: davinci resolve preferences]

I've tried different speaker configuration without any difference.

Answer (score 0):

It is working for me in dr 17.4.3.

Also note, that aac is not currently (if ever will be) supported. Check with wav file.